# SecurityException while using a DataPager

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting the following error below when I run this page where I added a DataPager Control on my application.

> Security Exception
>
> Description:
>
> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
>      System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +0
>      System.Web.UI.NamespaceTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean throwOnError) +98
>      System.Web.UI.NamespaceTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs) +11
>      System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs) +127
>      System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType2(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags) +228
>      System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags) +28
>      System.Web.UI.RootBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs) +20
>      System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String tagName, IDictionary attribs, TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder parentBuilder, String id, Int32 line, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type& childType, Boolean defaultProperty) +69
>      System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText) +526
>      System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) +926

Below is the code

```
       <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/CIOSMasterNonAuth.master"           AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ViewOrdersChanged.aspx.vb" Inherits="ViewOrders" title="Untitled Page" %>

        <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
        <%--<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>--%>
                     <asp:Table runat="server" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                     <asp:TableRow>
                     <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right">
                     <asp:Label runat="server">Order Status: </asp:Label>
                   </asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left">
           <asp:DropDownList ID="OrderStatusDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Verified" Value="V" />
         <asp:ListItem Text="New" Value="N" />
         <asp:ListItem Text="Cancelled" Value="C" />
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                         </asp:TableCell>
                      </asp:TableRow>
                                                       <asp:TableRow>
                       <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                          <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
                                       <table border="1" visible="false">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Web Order ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Web Entry Date
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Protocol Number
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Site Number
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Pharmacist of Record
                        </th>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkOrderDetails" Text='<%# Eval("web_order_id") %>' OnClick="lnkOrderDetails_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWebEntryDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("web_entry_date") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblProtocolNum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("protocol_num") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSiteNum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("site_num") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPharmName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PharmName") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>                        
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
                                  <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

           <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowModalPopup" style="display:none"/>
           <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="btnShowModalPopup"
     PopupControlID="divPopUp" 
    PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

           <div id="divPopUp" style="display:none; font-family:Georgia; font-size:small;">
            <asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="panelDragHandle" BackColor="#009999" BorderColor="ActiveBorder" BorderStyle="Ridge" ForeColor="White" Width="800px">
            <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
         Hold here to Drag this Box
        </td>
        <td align="right">
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblText" Text="Web OrderID: " ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>

            <asp:Label ID="lblWebOrderID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td colspan="2"> 
               <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" >

     <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="line_id" HeaderText="Line Item"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="no_of_participants" HeaderText="Number of Participants" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="amt_inventory" HeaderText="Current Inventory"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="nsc_num" HeaderText="NSC number"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="drug_name" HeaderText="Drug name"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="dose_str" HeaderText="Dose Strength"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="dose_unit" HeaderText="Dose Unit"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="dose_form_comment" HeaderText="Dose Form"/>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="dose_mult" HeaderText="Dose Mult" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="amt_req" HeaderText="Amt Required"/>
     </Columns>
     </asp:GridView> 
     </td> 
     </tr>
     <tr> 
                       <td colspan="2" align="right">                       
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </asp:Panel>
   <br />

</div>


              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"   ConnectionString="
               <%$ ConnectionStrings:CIOSConnectionString3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT w.web_order_id, w.web_entry_date, w.site_num, w.protocol_num, w.inv_num, w.pharm_num, w.status, w.Comments, w.UserName, w.porStatus, ISNULL(p.Pharm_fname, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(p.Pharm_lname, ' ') AS 'PharmName' FROM Web_Shipping AS w INNER JOIN Pharmacist_of_record AS p ON p.pharm_num = w.pharm_num WHERE (w.status = @status) ORDER BY w.web_order_id DESC" >
         <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="OrderStatusDropDownList" Name="Status" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="Char" />
                </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CIOSConnectionString3 %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT Web_Ship_detail.line_id, Web_Ship_detail.no_of_participants, Web_Ship_detail.Amt_inventory, Web_Ship_detail.NSC_num, Web_Ship_detail.Dose_str, Web_Ship_detail.Dose_unit, Web_Ship_detail.Dose_mult, Web_Ship_detail.amt_req, Drug.Drug_name, Dosage_Form.dose_form_comment FROM Web_Ship_detail INNER JOIN Drug ON Web_Ship_detail.NSC_num = Drug.NSC_Num INNER JOIN Dosage_Form ON Web_Ship_detail.Dose_form = Dosage_Form.dose_form WHERE (Web_Ship_detail.web_order_id = @web_order_id) ORDER BY Web_Ship_detail.line_id">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblWebOrderID" Name="web_order_id" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="Decimal" />
        </SelectParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" 
                   PagedControlID="OrderStatusDropDownList" 
                   PageSize="5"  runat="server">
      <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" 
            ShowFirstPageButton="true" 
            ShowLastPageButton="true"
            ShowNextPageButton="true"  
            ShowPreviousPageButton="true"  />
       </Fields>

    </asp:DataPager>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve this? Simple search for this exception turns quite a number of suggestions. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084219/the-application-attempted-to-perform-an-operation-not-allowed-by-the-security-po

Comment: I added a control DataPager which is giving an error.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".