# Security Exception - Port 587 SmtpPermission (email send by Gmail in Asp.net C# 4.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

I am sending mail from below code in asp.net with C# (4.0). I have windows shared hosting from re-seller club. When I send email from my online web page I got port 587 error. [image]).

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com");
    mm.Subject = "This is my subject";
    mm.Body = "This is Email Body";
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
NetworkCred.UserName = "from@gmail.com";
NetworkCred.Password = "*******";
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
smtp.Timeout = 20000;
smtp.Send(mm);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an error exactly like this before, however, I can only assume based on the message that the application doesn't have sufficient permissions wherever it's located.

I have located a few articles that may be able to help you. I have also provided snippets from "said" articles.

1) [The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084219/the-application-attempted-to-perform-an-operation-not-allowed-by-the-security-po)

2) [http://forums.iis.net/t/1189018.aspx?Change+the+application+s+trust+level](http://forums.iis.net/t/1189018.aspx?Change%20the%20application%20s%20trust%20level)

3) http://kb.odin.com/en/124321

Try one of the following in your web.config and see if this makes an impact:

1)

```
<location allowOverride="false">
<system.web>
    ...
    <trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />
</system.web>
```

2)

```
<securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel  name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
</securityPolicy>
```

3)

```
 <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```

I'm not 100% sure on the impact this may have with regards to security, so I would suggesting checking this for yourself, however, I hope this helps.