# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts, previously working code

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-config

**Summary:**

I'm getting a 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts, previously working code' error when trying to connect to a MySQL database through an ASP.NET web application. Full error is below.

The odd thing is that I developed the application in just a temporary new website project and everything works fine there. However, when I work it into the offline version of the website I'm trying to implement it in, this error crops up. Interestingly, I'm actually using a connection string that is already set up and operating correctly within the website. So I'm confused as to why my code operates elsewhere, and the connection string operated elsewhere, but when I try to use them together, I get the 'Unable to connect' error.

**What I've tried:**

The first thing was obviously to check that my connection string was formatted properly. I did double check this, but as I said the connection string already was (and still does) work with other pages on the site.

I also saw a number of posts regarding this error that suggested I include the  tag in the web.config file. This however did not fix the issue for me.

I also verified that my MySQL database is up and operational. As stated, I can get the connection string I'm using to work with other aspects of the page.

**Code Snippets:**

**Full error:**

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the     specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the     permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
 at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) 
at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.CheckCacheRemote(EndPoint& remoteEP, Boolean isOverwrite) 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.CreateSocketStream(IPAddress ip, Boolean unix) at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() 
The action that failed was: Demand 
The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Net.SocketPermission 
The first permission that failed was: 
The demand was for: 
The granted set of the failing assembly was: 
The assembly or AppDomain that failed was: MySql.Data, Version=6.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d 
The method that caused the failure was: System.IO.Stream CreateSocketStream(System.Net.IPAddress, Boolean) 
The Zone of the assembly that failed was: Intranet The Url of the assembly that failed was: file://PROAPPSRV/inetpub/wwwroot/MyChiller/bin/MySql.Data.DLL -    
-- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at     MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() at     MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) at     MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() 
at TCCVC_Login.ValidateUser(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

**C# MySQL connector:**

```
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newrst110ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT custpass AS hash, (lastlogin IS NOT NULL) AS firstLogin FROM rts110.mychiller_users
                                        WHERE custusername = @user";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Login1.UserName);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                DataTable returnTable = new DataTable();
                returnTable.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();

                // UPDATE LAST LOGIN DATE
                cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE mychiller_users
                                        SET lastLogin = CURDATE()
                                        WHERE custusername = @userName";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Login1.UserName);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.Dispose();

                // . . . 
                // Additional code down here that handles the return and closes the connection.
```

**Connection String:**

```
<add name="newrst110ConnectionString" connectionString="Datasource=70.103.118.100;Database=rts110;uid=####;pwd=####;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Does anyone have an idea why I'm running into this error when the individual components all see to operate correctly?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

I've been tinkering around more with this to see if I can narrow the problem down any. I've noticed when I make a test page and just create the very base connector below, I get an application security error, also below.

**Simple Connector**

```
DataTable returnTable = new DataTable();

    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["workorderConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM workorder.jobnumber";

                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                returnTable.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lbltest.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Application Error:**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +54
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.CheckCacheRemote(EndPoint& remoteEP, Boolean isOverwrite) +270
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +175
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +179
MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.CreateSocketStream(IPAddress ip, Boolean unix) +239
MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout) +650
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +366
```

Based on my google searched this again points back to the  tag in Web.Config file, which I already have included in there. Perhaps I'm including this incorrectly?

I'm wondering if maybe it might also be related to the two Web.config files I have (One in a subfolder with member pages, to restrict access without validated session). I tried adding the  in both and saw no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research on the application error I was getting with the simplified connection string I stumbled upon the following:

[The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084219/the-application-attempted-to-perform-an-operation-not-allowed-by-the-security-po)

After looking at the answer to that question, I moved my solution to my local drive, because I was running it from a server folder. Doing so solved the issue and everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach a version of your connectionstring? It seems that there might be a misconfiguration on your config file.

Comment: I've edited my question to add the connection string, but as I said, that connection string works successfully with other aspects of the same website.